# function me devuelve toda la funcion

Tags: funciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][![soy muy nuevo en esto, estoy viendo lo que es funciones y si bien es algo que me cuesta, algo estoy entendiendo. el problema es que quiero generear un alert con el resultado y me genera uno con toda la funcion. cual seria la forma correcta de hacerla. en mi caso estoy haciendo:

```
function alo(a){
    return a - 2;
}

alo (90);
alert('hola ' + alo) ][2]][2]
```

Comment: deebes hacer el llamado a la funcion `alert('hola ' + alo(90)) `

Comment: Recuerda que si solo llamas alo no te va a arrojar ningún resultado, debes invocarla con paréntesis y su argumento dentro del alert